# Remove a number of delimiters from each line of file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file which I need to load into a database. It has a delimiter of pipe (`|`) however each line contains different number of pipes. Using a batch script, how can I remove pipes from each line so the same number of pipes are on each line?

Example of file:

```
1|2|3||||||  
4|5|6|||  
7|8||||||
```

Let's say I'd like 5 pipes on each line only so it looks like:

```
1|2|3|||  
4|5|6|||  
7|8||||
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**  See second solution and limitation updates.

---

Example file.txt contents

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|G
1|2|3|4|5|6|7
!|@|#|$|%|^|&
]1|]2|]3|]4|]5|]6|]7

|Two||Four||||Eight

!@$%^&%^*(){}|[]';/.,<>/|
Lonely||||||||||||||||||
Sep|er|ate| From| Th|e |W||orld | |
```

---

**First Solution**

Here is a simple way to do what you want.  It should not have any problems with special characters.

Limitations

1. It only supports up to <s>24</s> 25 columns as it is currently written. `%%A to %%Y`
2. <s>The first value may not begin with `]`.</s> Replaced `for /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%Y in ('type file.txt ^| find /v /n ""') do (` with `for /F "delims=" %%Z in ('type file.txt') do (`.
3. "Empty" fields may only appear at the end of every line. **See second solution.**
4. Does not preserve blank lines in the file.  (This can be fixed if desired.)

Just specify how many and which columns you want to keep. For example `tokens=3-5,12,48-50` will select only columns 3,4,5,12,48,49,50.  Make sure you add on or remove the variables to match the output you want. `echo %%A^|%%B^|%%D^|%%C^|%%G^|%%E^|%%F`.  Note that the columns can be reordered as well in the echo statement.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%Z in ('type file.txt') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=|" %%A in ("%%Z") do (
        echo %%A^|%%B^|%%C^|%%D^|%%E
    )
)
endlocal
pause >nul
```

You can either redirect the output of the .bat file into a new file `Script.bat>output.txt` or output the echo command to a file by appending `>>output.txt` to the echo line.

Example Output:

```
A|B|C|D|E
1|2|3|4|5
!|@|#|$|%
]1|]2|]3|]4|]5
Two|Four|Eight||                  <-- Note that this line exhibits limit 3.
!@$%^&%^*(){}|[]';/.,<>/|||
Lonely||||
Sep|er|ate| From| Th
```

---

**Second Solution**

Shares only limitations **1** and **4**.  Currently adds spaces into existing blank columns to preserve all columns.  They can be removed with a further code change, but will not add unless desired by the OP.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%Z in ('type file.txt') do (
    set "xLine=|%%Z"
    call :Parse xLine
)
endlocal
pause >nul
goto :eof

:Parse
call set "xLine=%%%~1:||=| |%%"
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=|" %%A in ("%xLine%") do (
    echo %%A^|%%B^|%%C^|%%D^|%%E
)
goto :eof
```

Example Output:

```
A|B|C|D|E
1|2|3|4|5
!|@|#|$|%
]1|]2|]3|]4|]5
 |Two| |Four|
!@$%^&%^*(){}|[]';/.,<>/|||
Lonely| | | |
Sep|er|ate| From| Th
```

Comment: Nice, but you should probably extend your limitation "list" with what @jeb noted. Basically, ``2. The first value may not begin with `]`.`` and `3. "Empty" fields may only appear at the end of every line.` If either of those is not satisfied, your solution corrupts data (changes values or repositions fields).

Comment: You can avoid the `]` limitation with `for /F "tokens=1,* delims=" %%Y in ('findstr /n ^^ file.txt') DO ( set "line=%%Y" setlocal EnableDelayed Expansion set "line=!line:*:=!"` ...

Comment: @jeb  I have updated my answer with more clarity and some resolutions for the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to achieve this process, so each character must be revised in order to count the number of pipes in each line. It works, but it is somewhat slow.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Number of desired pipes
set limit=5
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   rem Get position of last character
   set last=0
   for /L %%b in (12,-1,0) do (
      set /A "last|=1<<%%b"
      for %%c in (!last!) do if "!line:~%%c,1!" equ "" set /A "last&=~1<<%%b"
   )
   rem Copy each character to result, but just %limit% number of pipes
   set pipes=0
   set result=
   for /L %%c in (0,1,!last!) do (
      if "!line:~%%c,1!" neq "|" (
         set "result=!result!!line:~%%c,1!"
      ) else (
         set /A pipes+=1
         if !pipes! leq %limit% set "result=!result!|"
      )
   )
   echo !result!
)
```

Previous program will fail if the input line contain exclamation marks.

Output:

```
1|2|3|||
4|5|6|||
7|8||||
```

Antonio